# Angular 14 PWA will not run in landscape mode, configured manifest file, latest Android

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have configured the manifest.webmanifest file as follow and yet the app will not launch as landscape mode (testing latest Android):

```
{
  "name": "SignStudio",
  "short_name": "SignStudio",
  "theme_color": "#434342",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "display": "standalone",
  "orientation": "landscape",
  "scope": "https://galaxy.americas.me/signstudio/",
  "start_url": "signstudio/",
```

app always loads in whatever the device mode is on (portrait or landscape).

trying to force it to always landscape,

any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to use property CSS which mean is orientation:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) and (orientation: portrait) {
#feature {
display: none;
}

#message {
display: block;
}
}
```

and something like this

```
@media screen and (max-width: 425px) and (orientation: landscape) {
#feature {
display: block;
}

#message {
display: none;
}
}
```

You can try to add some element HTML (ex: p tag) that the user can use the feature if the orientation mobile is landscape. I hope you can imagine what I mean.

What I suggest doesn't make mobile orientation auto landscape but I try to force users to change the orientation mobile.